# What is the data collection limit for Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, nintex

What is the data collection limit for Sharepoint? I am storing data to a Sharepoint list submitted through the form (NinText form).

I am expecting about 6525 list entries (or aka *365
round 145 rows required each day. There is about 43 Correctional Centres 2.4million list entries.

Is there a limit to the number of list entries that a SharePoint can have?

I am using Sharepoint on-premise (aka not the online version).

And, then on another page, I am traversing through the list data as below. I feel like traversing 2.4 million list entries would make this slow! Any suggestions?

```
            $.get(siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&XMLDATA=TRUE&List=" + listId, function(xml) {
                zrow = xml.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
                for(var i=0; i<zrow.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the official [Software Boundaries on Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits) we're only talking about a supported count of items within a content databased and thresholds for views, crawled and indexed items not about boundaries of list entries.
So possible problems you may face are about searching and indexing not about list item count.

Comment: Thanks. I found that overall in a year I am expecting about 4 million list entries. Searching that sequentially using for loop would probably be degrading right?

Comment: yes, degrading, uncomfortable, time consuming and not preferable. Such a mass of data is a case for equivalent data mining strategies, intelligent filter requests, grouping and specific search. If you plan to do something like update all the items in any case then never by GUI or workflow. Only a PowerShell task could avoid a bad performance but even this would last quite long.

Comment: I am in trouble. Do not know how to crack this crackpot!